# What kind of dynamic container and internal containers should I use for this intended view?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I want to make a popup which has a person's details on it. Each detail will be stacked vertically in the popup.  I have two questions.

(1) How should I deal (graphically) with details which are not available?
(2) How to make the container around all the details dynamic so that its height is determined by the number of details available.

My first thought was the following;

```
<StackPanel Width="400"
                Height="500">
        <StackPanel x:Name="sp">
            <Grid x:Name="spTelephone" Height="50">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid   Grid.Column="0">
                    <Ellipse Fill="Blue"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Column="1"
                      Margin="5,0,0,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="+Some Phone No."
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               FontFamily="Verdana"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid   Grid.Column="2">
                    <Ellipse Fill="Blue"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid   Grid.Column="3">
                    <Ellipse Fill="Blue"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="spMobile"  Height="50">
                <!-- Repeat of above -->
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="spEmail" Height="50">
                <!-- Repeat of above -->
            </Grid>
        <!-- Further Grids -->
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

The idea being that if a detail is not available then I would set the Visibility property of the GRID to Visibility.Collapsed.

For example see my image with 3 details.
[image]

Then if a cell phone is not available it would look like this.
[image]

So how should I do this? I could for imagine using a ListView as well maybe as this would then take away the need to collapse the views.  I could add each detail to an Item.  But then how do I get the list view and its parent to resize its height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define datatemplate for item and use any items control to represent them.
Simple solution would be something like this:

Template

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyItemTemplate">
<Grid x:Name="spTelephone" Height="50">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid   Grid.Column="0">
        <Ellipse Fill="Blue"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1"
          Margin="5,0,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="+Some Phone No."
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   FontFamily="Verdana"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid   Grid.Column="2">
        <Ellipse Fill="Blue"
     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
     VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid   Grid.Column="3">
        <Ellipse Fill="Blue"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Control

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection}" 
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemTemplate}"/>
</Border>
```

Of course you must fill collection from dataContext and for *Text="+Some Phone No."* also use data binding from current collection item.(Use DataContext={Binding} in template)

Border here is just to show that ItemsControl size changes according to collection-items count. Also ItemsControl can be replaced with any of it's descendants.